# Can a "feeling" be used as a synonym for an "emotion?"

Tags: synonyms, emotions

When the context is clearly about the heart (not the body in general), are "feelings" the same as "emotions?"

The only use I really care about is like this:

> It can help you if you are aware of the emotions [feelings] of joy,
>   peace, anger or sadness.

In above example, is it OK to use the term "feelings" to describe heart feelings that just happen in someone's heart without further consideration?

I've read [here](https://www.laughteronlineuniversity.com/feelings-vs-emotions/) that emotions and feelings are not the same:

> Essentially emotions are physical and instinctive...*You see a
>   lion, and you instantly get scared.*
>
> Feelings on the other hand play out in our heads... *You see a
>   lion behind bars, and your feelings may range from curiosity to
>   admiration.*

In this case, feelings sound like emotions with an attitude, so more conscious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That distinction you posted is reasonable, but not necessarily proscriptive. I think you could use feelings here. Think of it from this point of view; "emotion" is a foreign term, while "feel" is native Germanic English. Not too long ago, you would have been able to meet people who didn't know the word "emotion". It's thus from a more educated stratum of the language. Before its widespread adoption, people would have used "feelings" alone.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: native Germanic English?

Comment: Cheers, Jan! Though don't take my word for it, just giving you my own "feelings" on the matter! Lambie: I just mean it's a difference between our own old inherited vocabulary and newer words adopted from French, Latin or whatever.

Comment: Right. Well, it does come from German in part it seems but seems somewhat passive whereas emotion comes from the Latin to excite and somehow involves movement. emoveo: move out, stir up or agitate. Interesting....

Comment: @BenMcGah...OK; all emotions are feelings, but feelings can be more than just emotions...

Comment: The word "mood" used to have a wider semantic field, I gather, if we're thinking about Old English. I'm reminded of older use of "transport" with this "movement" sense in emotion too, like "transports of delight" and so on.

Comment: If they're in the lexis, they're **_our own_** 'newer words adopted from French, Latin or whatever'.

Comment: Sure they are, but there's often a sense of their being less "intimate", and less appropriate for certain more folksy or domestic contexts, so the difference is often worth noting.